# how to save hindi characters in mysql through json request using java code

Tags: java, sql, spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/MultiLingual", method = RequestMethod.GET,consumes={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
@ResponseBody public String hi(@RequestParam("name") String name ,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {

    httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    System.out.println(name +"(((((((( अलविदा");

    int update  = jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO multi_lingual(Name) values(?)",name);
    String nameAlvida = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("Select name from multi_lingual order by ID DESC limit 0,1", String.class);
    System.out.println(update+" ::: update"); 
    if(update>0)
    {
        System.out.println("inserted");

    }
     System.out.println(" "+StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(name));

    return "success = "    +nameAlvida;

}
```

Comment: When you print name `System.out.println(name +"(((((((( अलविदा");` are you able to see hindi characters??

Comment: When you create the database in mysql set `Default characterset` to `utf8` and set `Default collation` to `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi It is printing multiple ????? instead of अलविदा and default collation and character set to utf8 and utf8_general_ci respectively, But still it doesnt work.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi Also It is storing some value like à¤?à¤²à¤µà¤¿à¤¦à¤¾ in MYSQL, but in another API in which I am getting this value, got the same encoded things as response.

Comment: In console it will print ??? only (you have to make console utf_8) enable. Try to insert into mysql (let it be what it is inserting) and retrieve the data and print it in some JSP page. Check if its showing correct character set in JSP page. And also through JSP `page` directive make it `UTF-8`.

Comment: sorry.. its not working yet ... printing the same content which is saved in MYSQL  i.e..     à¤à¤²à¤µà¤¿à¤¦à¤¾ . even i also include this ......

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a few changes.

```
#update Table properties
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

#update database properties
datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```